# JdbcTemplate query doesn't succeed

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I want to make a simple select from a database, and my query doesn't find a record which exists in the database.

```
String sql = "SELECT id FROM Users where Name=?";

Object [] params = { name };
int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR};

jdbc.queryForList(sql, params, types, String.class);
```

I tried different queries but I couldn't get it to work. I just want to check if the name exists in the database.

Edit:

I get the following message:

```
XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
SQLErrorCodesFactory:126 - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
```

Comment: use Integer.class as elementType(4th param), if 'id' is an Integer. Also just verify that type of name is int or String.

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get an error, or just no results? Do you access the database in any other way, and is that successful?

Comment: I did that and nothing's changed. I added the message I get to a question. I do access database with different queries successfully.

Comment: What you posted is not an error message. What does the method return? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Ok, i solved it, I didn't have the rights to the table.